# Green spaces show up on Cloud9 for my EC2 instance on AWS when I tab or try to and a space?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloud9

Every time I try to tab or create white space the cloud9 editor shows green lines. I'm not sure about what data value that is but it is making it impossible to write anything. Seeing if you would know a solution to this white space issue.

You see the green lines, that is supposed to be whitespace. Happens all over the page.

Answer (score 0):

Are these green lines on the left side of the editor window? If so those are there to show that you've changed that line from the original. Don't worry, they aren't characters stored in the file itself.

I believe it only appears if the file in in a git repo.

Comment: Thank you. I think I did add something extra like a white space monitor. It just looks bad to the eye I shouldn't have added it. Thanks though.

Comment: No problem. Overall Cloud9 has a fair amount of UI bugs that need to be ironed out.